# How can I show a div or html element after submitting a form and retrieve some information from a view in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Currently when the user introduces a string in an input field and clicks the submit button, this invokes a view that returns through `return render(request, 'index.html', context)` a context that
it basically contains data that is displayed in a table.

I would like said table to be visible only after submitting the form and not before and that when it is visible it shows the information obtained from the view.

The problem is that if through inline styling I make this table not visible, for example in the following way:

```
<div class="row" id="searchVariantTable" style="display: none;">
    <!-- SOME TABLE HERE-->
</div>
```

And then I use the `onsubmit` event for form or `onclick` for button, it doesn't work. (It works partially, I can see the `tbody` but `thead` is missing, so basically I can't display the retrieved data from the database).

Similarly, if I try something like this:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#searchVariantTable').hide();
  $('form').submit(function(e) {
      $('#searchVariantTable').show();
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

It doesn't work either.

I think the last option, if I'm not mistaken, is AJAX, but I'm not quite sure how to do something like that with Django (it's my first time using Django)

What am I doing wrong? Is there an option that I am missing?

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` prevents the form request being sent to the server. The default form submit process will then reload new page based on whatever you render server side. suggest you study some tutorials on how forms work and how ajax submits work

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, yeah I am reading the official django docs, and trying to find some examples but couldn't find a good one covering this case. Even if I remove the `e.preventDefault();` it's still not working.

Comment: Unfortunately "not working" is a virtually meaningless when it comes to debugging. Need s much detail about what is working, what is happening, where (server side or browser), etc. ALso good to learn how to get error details both from browser dev tools and server side errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try by using if else in django template:

```
index.html
<form method="post">
<input type="submit">
</form>
{% if allowed == "yes" %}
<!-- your table code -->
{% endif %}


and in views.py
if request.method == "POST":
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'allowed':'yes'})

else:
    return render(request,'index.html',{'allowed':'no'})
```

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing something similar.